# Is there a way to suppress *only* exhaustiveness checking in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I find myself writing the code like this a lot:

```scala
thing match {
   case Case1 ...
   case Case2 ...
   case _ => throw new IllegalStateException(s"unexpected $thing")
}
```

Sometimes I *want* a runtime error when the cases don't match. The cases are a form of assertion.

Is there a better way to suppress the exhaustiveness check?

I don't want to use `[@unchecked](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/unchecked.html)` because that would also disable reachability checking, which I do want.

Comment: I personally believe it is better the way you have it, since at least you can put a better exception in place. You may write your own helper using a partial function if you want to reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you are doing?

Comment: @texasbruce it's a lot of repetition, and I have to do `// $COVERAGE_OFF` and `// $COVERAGE_ON` every time. I'm working on a compiler and have certain expectations of the AST such that if my assumptions are wrong, I want to blow up as soon as possible. It doesn't seem worth it to make bad ASTs unrepresentable, since a large test suite will catch unexpected ASTs anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `nowarn` annotation to hide warning:

```
import scala.annotation.nowarn

@nowarn("msg=not.*?exhaustive")
val r = thing match {
   case Case1 ...
   case Case2 ...
}
```

It was added in Scala **2.13.2** so if you're using an older version you will need to use to [silencer](https://github.com/ghik/silencer) plugin.

Alternatively, with a silencer plugin, you could set up [global regex-based suppresion](https://github.com/ghik/silencer#global-regex-based-suppression).

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try. I don't think it's a good solution, though, because the checks are still happening.
 I still get a lot of warnings: `Exhaustivity analysis reached max recursion depth, not all missing cases are reported.` and (more importantly!) slow compilation times. Both of which go away if I add catch-all clauses

Comment: Are you sure it's not another problem? Please check this [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rvnRdvwMT5qSRlZ4T3hEhg), it shows that using `nowarn` makes warning go away, but of course, only for this particular case, you showed.

Comment: To suppress other warnings you'd need to try to adjust regex in `nowarn`.

Comment: Running the checks anyway and then suppressing them with a regex isn't exactly what I'm looking for: the checks can get really expensive: for a small project they nearly double compile time as compared to when I add catch-all clauses.

Comment: Update: `@nowarn` has been back-ported to 2.12.13 https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.12.13